# VLC doesn't play video with Dokan

Tags: windows, video, vlc, dokan

I'm using [dokany](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany) version of Dokan, to mount a disk on the system.

I've managed to implement all the necessary callbacks for the OS to be able to work with the dokan disk's files and folders.

Whenever I try to play a video file from the dokan disk with Media Player Classic, everything works great. When I try playing it with VLC, I get the following error:

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Bad file descriptor).
```

**UPDATE:**

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Bad file descriptor).
VLC can't recognize the input's format:
The format of 'file:///K:/%5BHorribleSubs%5D%20Fate%20Stay%20Night%20-%20Unlimited%20Blade%20Works%20-%2025%20%5B720p%5D.mkv' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.
```

And when I read VLC's debug data, I get the following messages:

```
core debug: adding item `[HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv' ( file:///K:/%5BHorribleSubs%5D%20Fate%20Stay%20Night%20-%20Unlimited%20Blade%20Works%20-%2025%20%5B720p%5D.mkv )
core debug: processing request item: [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv, node: null, skip: 0
core debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
core debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
core debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
core debug: resyncing on [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
core debug: [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv is at 0
core debug: creating new input thread
core debug: Creating an input for '[HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv'
core debug: Creating an input for '[HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv'
core debug: requesting art for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
core debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\MRSTUD~1\AppData\Local\Temp'
core debug: `file:///K:/%5BHorribleSubs%5D%20Fate%20Stay%20Night%20-%20Unlimited%20Blade%20Works%20-%2025%20%5B720p%5D.mkv' gives access `file' demux `' path `/K:/%5BHorribleSubs%5D%20Fate%20Stay%20Night%20-%20Unlimited%20Blade%20Works%20-%2025%20%5B720p%5D.mkv'
core debug: specified demux `any'
core debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/K:/%5BHorribleSubs%5D%20Fate%20Stay%20Night%20-%20Unlimited%20Blade%20Works%20-%2025%20%5B720p%5D.mkv' file='K:\[HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv'
core debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 12 candidates
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
core debug: searching art for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
core debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
core debug: searching art for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
core debug: no access_demux modules matched
core debug: creating access 'file' location='/K:/%5BHorribleSubs%5D%20Fate%20Stay%20Night%20-%20Unlimited%20Blade%20Works%20-%2025%20%5B720p%5D.mkv', path='K:\[HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv'
core debug: looking for access module matching "file": 21 candidates
filesystem debug: opening file `K:\[HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv'
core debug: using access module "filesystem"
core debug: Using stream method for AStream*
core debug: starting pre-buffering
filesystem error: read error: Invalid argument
core error: cannot pre fill buffer
core debug: removing module "filesystem"
core warning: cannot create a stream_t from access
core debug: finished input
core debug: dead input
core debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
core debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
core debug: removing module "lua"
core debug: searching art for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
core debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
core debug: removing module "lua"
core debug: searching art for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
core debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\MrStudent\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
```

Please help me with this issue. I'm out of ideas :\

**UPDATE:**

Sometimes, this error pops up:

```
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for [HorribleSubs] Fate Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works - 25 [720p].mkv
core debug: using access module "filesystem"
core debug: Using stream method for AStream*
core debug: starting pre-buffering
filesystem error: read error: Invalid argument
core error: cannot pre fill buffer
core debug: removing module "filesystem"
core warning: cannot create a stream_t from access
core debug: finished input
core debug: dead input
core debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
core debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
...
mkv error: cannot load some cues/chapters/tags etc. (broken seekhead or file)
...
mkv error: cannot find any cluster, damaged file ?
...
es error: cannot peek
...
core error: no suitable demux module for `file/any:///K:/%5BHorribleSubs%5D%20Fate%20Stay%20Night%20-%20Unlimited%20Blade%20Works%20-%2025%20%5B720p%5D.mkv'
```

Comment: I've opened an issue in dokany's github. [See it here](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/issues/34)

Comment: Here's a link to an "API Monitor" [log file](http://www.filedropper.com/vlc_2).
The log file was created with [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/downloads).

Comment: For small files, at first, VLC prints the same error.
After I hit play, VLC prints the error several times and then starts the movie!
It might be a latency problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to update [DokanNet](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet) to its latest version.

The video works fluently now!